# C++ proper singleton use case

Tags: c++, oop, architecture, stl, singleton

I'm making a game to practice good design/arch and I think I programmed myself into a check. I'm not sure if my architecture is clean right now, some advice would be clutch.

I have a `class Game` that holds an instance of `class GraphicsManager` `class InputManager` and `class StateManager`

The graphics manager handles sdl stuff as does the input manager. the state manager is a stack of abstract type `class GameState`

Each frame, the game calls update on the GameState at the top of the state stack and passes said state a StateManager pointer so that the GameState can push a new state or pop itself from the stack.

`GameState* currentState = stateManager.getState() //return top`
`currentState.update(&stateManager) // state might change here`

The issue is when I introduce my `class Screen`. Screen should be owned by the various implementations of GameState, so if I had OpeningState I'd expect for it to own OpeningScreen. 
The issue is, Screen needs access to the Graphics instance to get a pointer to the SDL_Renderer and I don't see a good place to pass that pointer down. Passing the pointer from Game --> GameState --> Screen feels kind of funky.

I feel like I need to turn each 'Manager' into a singleton but if theres something more elegant I'd love to learn

heres my spaghetti code for ref https://github.com/MicahMartin/FightingGame/tree/master/src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use singleton instead of injecting your dependencies explicitly but be aware that this design leads to a less testable code and high functional coupling between components.  Other ecosystems have addressed this issue introducing means to inject dependencies in a declarative fashion, thanks to frameworks that provide mechanism to replace actual depencencies with "test doubles". Check out how Spring MVC works with Java applications.

If you're sure that this is what you need, you could use a similar (but still less flexible) approach implementing a "service locator" pattern which consists in a single point that holds pointers to instances of "injectable" objects

```
ServiceLocator::inject<Screen*>(new Screen () , "screen1")

//

...

//
Screen* s = ServiceLocator::getInstance<Screen*>("screen1")
```

In this way you can avoid to pass pointers around and at same time be more decoupled. Now suppose that you have a MockScreen that inherits from Screen. Suppose also that you want to test the method int MyClass::workWithScreen() which depends on an instance of Screen referenced with the label "screen1". You can write your test like

```
Myclass unitUnderTest;
ServiceLocator::inject<Screen*>(new MockScreen () , "screen1");

int result = unitUnderTest.workWithScreen()

assert ....
```

I'll leave you as exercise to implement the service locator!

Keep in mind that, in this way, your are introducing in your code also the drawbacks of dependency injection: the worst of them is that you loose the control over the design of your component layout, every object can access every object. This is not a big issue when you are developing some REST api handler which is based on solid and well known architectural pattern (controller -> service -> repository -> db and then go back) but you have to be careful in other contexts!

Comment: Thank you so much for this suggestion! everyone has been telling me to just go with a singleton but this is beautiful, you're the best.